# Why do I get a strange blank screen error with OpenGLes/Android/NDK?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, opengl-es-1.1, spritebatch

I'm getting a very weird error ever since I have "ported" the spritebatch code from [Nokia's site](http://projects.developer.nokia.com/spritebatchqt/browser/src_gles11spritebatch/GLES11SpriteBatch.cpp). It runs well as a desktop applcation emulated by POWERVR. But on Android I only get a blank screen (in fact its black.) This happens if I just try to display a image, but it doesn't crash.

Here is where comes the weird part comes in: if i put `glGeterror();` in the update function it works fine! (slowly, but displays everything fine) and `geterror` code returns `0`. I have no idea what is going on or how to debug it, as I'm new to OpenGL but everything looks correct in the source. I spitted geterrors all around the code but without any clue. I've attached [my project](http://gjteam.com.br/bareproject.zip) if you want to take a look. You will need Visual Studio + vsandroid to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently the problem is not on the sprite batch, but in the java code. I replaced for another one that uses surface view and no longer im getting this esotheric behavior.